# How to retrieve JSON data in PHP posted from terminal using CURL

Tags: php, json, curl

I am using CURL installed in ubuntu to send JSON to PHP page.There in that page I'm trying to decode JSON data and store into DB.

Here it the command used to send JSON

```
 curl -i -X POST -d '{"Customer":{"first_name":"First name","last_name":"last name","email":"email@gmail.com","addresses":{"address1":"some address","city":"city","country":"CA","first_name":"Mother","last_name":"Lastnameson","phone":"555-1212","province":"ON","zip":"123 ABC"}}}' https://phpserver-chaturasan.c9users.io/listener.php
```

Output on terminal:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 05:32:25 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
x-powered-by: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17
set-cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=cloud9ide; expires=Tue, 19-Jul-2016     06:32:25 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
set-cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=cloud9ide; expires=Tue, 19-Jul-2016 06:32:25 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
vary: Accept-Encoding
content-length: 947
keep-alive: timeout=5, max=100
content-type: text/html
X-BACKEND: apps-proxy

/home/ubuntu/workspace/listener.php:11:
string(258) "{"Customer":{"first_name":"First name","last_name":"last name","email":"email@gmail.com","addresses":{"address1":"some address","city":"city","country":"CA","first_name":"Mother","last_name":"Lastnameson","phone":"555-1212","province":"ON","zip":"123 ABC"}}}"
hello world/home/ubuntu/workspace/listener.php:14:
array(1) {
  'Customer' =>
  array(4) {
    'first_name' =>
    string(10) "First name"
    'last_name' =>
    string(9) "last name"
    'email' =>
    string(15) "email@gmail.com"
    'addresses' =>
    array(8) {
      'address1' =>
      string(12) "some address"
      'city' =>
      string(4) "city"
      'country' =>
      string(2) "CA"
      'first_name' =>
      string(6) "Mother"
      'last_name' =>
      string(11) "Lastnameson"
      'phone' =>
      string(8) "555-1212"
      'province' =>
      string(2) "ON"
      'zip' =>
      string(7) "123 ABC"
    }
  }
}
```

PHP page code:

```
<?php 
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);
/*if(isset($_POST['Customer'])){
    $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","gen");
    $name = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['Scenes']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO g SET name = '$name'";
    $db->query($query);
}
*/

$jsonStr = file_get_contents("php://input"); //read the HTTP body.
var_dump($jsonStr);
echo "hello world";
$json = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
var_dump($json);
 /*db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","gen");
$query = "INSERT INTO g SET name = '$json'";
$db->query($query);*/
?>
```

but the output of page is

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/listener.php:11: string(0) "" hello world/home/ubuntu/workspace/listener.php:14: NULL
```

Now how do I store JSON data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what you are trying to achieve. But from your question, I am guessing that

1. You are making the cURL call from CLI (command line/terminal) with the JSON encoded data. Then you are processing the data.
2. You want that data to be somehow available when you hit the file through a webserver.

If that is the case then, you need to store the data in a `persistant storage` like a flat file in the most basic sense or a database like `MySQL` as per the commented out code, and then retrieve the same when needed, specially since php is stateless, every call is a new call for it.

Shall update the answer further once I get more clarity on what exactly is your problem.

Comment: Thank u for the answer I stored the json file directly into mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try my source. It's working well for me!!

```
$data_string = '{"Customer":{"first_name":"First name","last_name":"last name","email":"email@gmail.com","addresses":{"address1":"some address","city":"city","country":"CA","first_name":"Mother","last_name":"Lastnameson","phone":"555-1212","province":"ON","zip":"123 ABC"}}}';

$ch = curl_init('https://phpserver-chaturasan.c9users.io/listener.php');
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0", // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                      
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)));                                                                 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

My result

[image]

Comment: I had update my source. Because your link is https so need setopt_array with `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false` xD

Comment: @Chaturasan try it yet?

Comment: It shows perfectly in the page your are posting but at the listener page i.e the page where data is sent doesn't show the  same result

Comment: @Chaturasan I have use print_r. It's look good: ( [Customer] => Array ( [first_name] => First name [last_name] => last name [email] => email@gmail.com [addresses] => Array ( [address1] => some address [city] => city [country] => CA [first_name] => Mother [last_name] => Lastnameson [phone] => 555-1212 [province] => ON [zip] => 123 ABC ) ) )

Comment: @Chaturasan I'm try in my localhost data received by listener look good!!

Comment: I directly stored the json file $jsonStr = file_get_contents("php://input"); //read the HTTP body.
echo "hello world";
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","gen");
$query = "INSERT INTO g SET name = '$jsonStr'";
$db->query($query);

Comment: Yes It's ok. @Chaturasan